# Tcl Remove all characters after a string without removing the string

Tags: regex, tcl

In `tcl` is there a way to trim out all character AFTER a designated string? I have seen lots of posts on removing all after and including the string but not what I am hoping to do. I have a script that searches for file names with the suffix `.sv` but some of them are `.sv.**bunch of random stuff**`. and I don't need the random stuff as it is not relevant to me.

I have experimented with different `regsub` and `string trim` commands but they always remove the `.sv` as well.

The results being appended to a list are similar to as follows...

```
test_module_1.sv.random_stuff
test_module_2.sv.random_stuff
test_module_3.sv.random_stuff
test_module_4.sv.random_stuff
test_module_5.sv.random_stuff
```

etc etc

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place match matched parts of a regex pattern when you use `regsub`. An example:

```
regsub {(\.sv).*} $str {\1} new
```

Will remove `.sv` and anything after it if any and replace that by the first matched group, that is the part between parens, or in this case, `.sv` so that an input of `example.sv.random` will become `example.sv`.

However, you can also easily replace with `.sv` like so:

```
regsub {\.sv.*} $str {.sv} new
```

Or another approach not involving replacing would be to get the part of the string up until the `.sv` part:

```
string range $str 0 [expr {[string first ".sv" $str]+2}]
```

Here `[string first ".sv" $str]` gets the position of `.sv` in the string (if there are multiple, it will get the first), adds 2 characters (`sv` after `.` are 2 chars long) to it and `string range` gets all characters up to and including `.sv`.

Or if you want to stick with regexes:

```
regexp {.+?\.sv} $str match
```

`$match` will contain the result string. The expression used grabs all characters up to and including `.sv`.

Comment: There are a few matches appended to a list and it seems to work for the first one but then completely clears the rest of the list (because they come after the .`sv`). Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: @LiamP so you have a list of strings? Loop through each one and apply one of the above options.